# Replacement for com.sun.faces.util.Util.createConstantMethodBinding(String action);

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am working on a migration project from JSF 1.1 to JSF 2.0, one of my custom component has this piece of code.

```
MethodBinding mb = com.sun.faces.util.Util.createConstantMethodBinding(
                        String action
                   );
((XYZComponent)component).setAction(mb);
```

Since this is from Sun jar I don't have the exact replacement in JSF 2.0. Would it be a right approach if I go ahead and change this to `createMethodExpression(..)` ?

If not please do suggest me the alternate approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

here is your code but using JSF MethodExpression.

```
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ELContext elContext = fc.getELContext();
            String action = "#{bean.doSomeThing(id)}";
            Class<?>[] parameterTypes = new Class[1];
            parameterTypes[0]=String.class;
            Class<? extends String> returnType = String.class;
            MethodExpression me = fc.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(elContext,action, returnType, parameterTypes);
            component.setActionExpression(me);
```